# What is the correct origin of the sound component 禺?

Tags: glyph-origin

After I came across the character 寓 (yù; residence), I wanted to know more about it's sound component 禺 (yú, yù; district/a mountain in Zhejiang) and it's origin.

Unfortunately though, there are many theories about this sound component and I cannot come to a conclusion on what this sound component original meaning or representation was.

Here's this sound component's ancient form for reference (Ancient forms from 小學堂):
[image]

Also for reference, here are what some of the following sources say about the origin of 禺:

- **《說文解字》**: Depiction of a kind of monkey with a ghost/demon-like head.
- **漢語多功能字庫, Dong Chinese**: Possibly a depiction of a reptile-like animal and may be related to 禹.
- **zi.tools**: Derived from 鬼, which depicts a ghost with an emphasized cranium. (Already checked the Old Chinese pronunciation, doesn't sound similar to each other.)
- **Kanji Networks**: Depicts a monkey with a curved back and a curved tail.
- **Alex Adler, The World of Kanji p. 71**: Depicts a person dancing with a skull mask on.
- **谷衍奎《汉字源流字典》p. 457-458**: Depicts a gorilla with it's head emphasized/protruding.
- I've tried looking up this component in Outlier Dictionary of Chinese Characters and 季旭昇 《說文新證》 but was unable to find any information about this component. Unless if I skipped out on any pages on 《說文新證》.

If anyone could assist in finding out the origin for this sound component, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think the unsatisfying answer to this one is "nobody knows for sure".

[漢語多功能字庫](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk//Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%A6%BA)

> 「禺」字構形初義不明
> [My translation] The origin of the form of the character 禺 is unclear.

This character has historically almost always been used as a phonetic loan for meanings unrelated to its form, so there's not a whole lot of evidence to work from.

That being said, I think the most convincing explanation among those you listed is that 禺 is a pictograph of a monkey, since 禺 seems to be cognate to words for monkey in Tibeto-Burman languages.

[https://stedt.berkeley.edu/~stedt-cgi/rootcanal.pl/etymon/2529#1.3.1](https://stedt.berkeley.edu/%7Estedt-cgi/rootcanal.pl/etymon/2529#1.3.1)

> #2529 PTB *ŋaːw APE / MONKEY
> Reconstructed mesoroots below:
> PKC *ŋaaw MONKEY (long tail / grey)
> PCN *ŋa MONKEY
> Chinese comparandum
> 禺 OC *ngi̯u, GSR #124a-b ‘monkey’; Schuessler 2007:617 *ŋoh; B & S 2011: (*ŋo‑s); Mand. yù.

Comment: This kind of makes a bit of sense honestly, as the ancient form that I'm seeing almost resembles a highly stylized simplified picture of a monkey in a way.

Answer (score 1):

Not my forté but I find this:

> Main pronunciation 主要发音: yú
>
> Other pronunciations 其它发音: yù,yú
>
> Original meaning 本义: Meaning a snake
>
> Character decomposition 字形分解 [?]:   Component 禺   from (not- 禸 róu).
> (name- hand-holding-snake 禺 yú)
>
> Decomposition notes 字形分解说明 [?]:   (- 禺 hand holding a snake)

Answer (score 1):

The content below is copied from 汉典 for your information. (https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E7%A6%BA)

[image]